# Filetime Struct Sort

Tags: winapi

I have a filetime structure, i just want to compare to see which one is older (my aim is to sort descending), so I was hoping to avoid `FileTimeToSystemTime`

These are my two structs:

```
var time1 = {
dwLowDateTime: 2944808535,
dwHighDateTime: 30434197
}
```

then

```
var time2 = {
dwLowDateTime: 3483262096,
dwHighDateTime: 30434432
}
```

I was wondering is there a reliable way to test which one is greater. Like can I just compare `dwHighDateTime`'s?

Thanks

Comment: FILETIME is a pita, you want to copy it into a LARGE_INTEGER so you can easily use its QuadPart member for comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can compare high parts, but they may be identical.

Compare high. If they are different, whichever is greater is greater. If same, compare low.

or convert them to LARGE_INTEGERs and compare those:

```
LARGE_INTEGER one;
one.HighPart = time1.dwHighDateTime;
one.LowPart = time1.dwLowDateTime;

LARGE_INTEGER two;
two.HighPart = time2.dwHighDateTime;
two.LowPart = time2.dwLowDateTime;

if (one.QuadPart > two.QuadPart) {
...
}
```

the reason you have to do it is that FILETIME predates availability of 64-bit instructions.

Comment: This should be a `ULARGE_INTEGER` instead, as spelled out in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx): *"It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the **FILETIME** structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should copy the low- and high-order parts of the file time to a **[ULARGE_INTEGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742.aspx)** structure, perform 64-bit arithmetic on the **QuadPart** member, and copy the **LowPart** and **HighPart** members into the **FILETIME** structure."*

Comment: true.My recommendation becomes incorrect 29600 years from now; yours will stand up for about 30K more years after that.

Comment: You are assuming that a `FILETIME` structure always holds the current time. This assumption is wrong today already. Consider an application that stores an expiration datetime, for example, and uses the value `0xffffffffffffffff` to mean *"never expires"*. Using a `LARGE_INTEGER` for sorting moves this value to the wrong end.